# Regular Expression (Python) to extract strings of text from inside of < and > - e.g. <stringone><string-two> etc

Tags: python, regex, string, tags, extract

I'm currently playing with the Stack Overflow data dumps and am trying to construct (what I imagine is) a simple regular expression to extract tag names from inside of `<` and `>` characters.  So, for each question, I have a list of one or more tags like `<tagone><tag-two>...<tag-n>` and am trying to extract just a list of tag names.  Here are a few example tag strings taken from the data dump:

```
<javascript><internet-explorer>

<c#><windows><best-practices><winforms><windows-services>

<c><algorithm><sorting><word>

<java>
```

For reference, I *don't* need to divide tag names into words, so for examples like `<best-practices>` I would like to get back `best-practices` (not `best` and `practices`).  Also, for what it's worth, I'm using Python if it makes any difference.  Any suggestions?

Comment: What format is the data dump in? XML? Json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the tag names of Stackoverflow do not have embedded `<` `>` you can use the regex:

```
<(.*?)>
```

or

```
<([^>]*)>
```

Explanation:

- `<` : A literal `<`
- `(..)` : To group and remember the
  match.
- `.*?` : To match anything in
  non-greedy way.
- `>` : A literal `<`
- `[^>]` : A char class to match
  anything other than a `>`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of doing data dumps (whatever they are) and using regex, you may be interested in using the [Stackoverflow API](https://stackapps.com/questions/1/api-documentation-and-help) and json instead.

For example, to cull the tags from this question, you could do this:

```
import urllib2
import json
import gzip
import cStringIO

f=urllib2.urlopen('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions/3708418?type=jsontext')
g=gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=cStringIO.StringIO(f.read()))
j=json.loads(g.read())

print(j['questions'][0]['tags'])
# [u'python', u'regex']
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
pattern = re.compile("<(.*?)>")
data = """
<javascript><internet-explorer>

<c#><windows><best-practices><winforms><windows-services>

<c><algorithm><sorting><word>

<java>
"""

for each in pattern.findall(data):
    print each
```

**Update**

**Statutory warning**: if the data dump is in XML or JSON (as one of the users commented) then you are much better off using a suitable XML or JSON parser.